# Asking user for yes|no input

Tags: ant, versioning

I am working on an Ant build process for an application that uses a versioning in the following format: major.minor.buildcount.  So currently the application is around 2.1.52, where we are on version 2.1 and there have been 35 builds.

I am now adding in an ant target to ask the user if they would like to advance the major version and/or the minor version.

When I run my target from the command line I would like to follow the following:

```
@@ ant version
Versioning application...
Would you like to advance the major version to 3? (Y|n)
@@ n
Not Advancing major version
Would you like to advance the minor version to 2? (y|N)
@@ y
Advancing minor version
```

The lines prepended with @@ is the user input that I would like to take.  My major and minor versions are stored in a build.properties file.

Here is my code so far

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="StudentMS" default="zip" basedir=".">
    <propertyfile file="./.ant/build.properties">
        <entry key="version.buildnumber" type="int" default="0" operation="+" pattern="00" />
    </propertyfile>

    <property file="./.ant/build.properties" />
    <property name="sourceDir" location="/Users/dave/Workspace/ColdFusion/StudentMs" />
    <property name="buildDir" location="${sourceDir}/builds" />

    <target name="version" description="Adds a major and minor version to the build.">
        <input message="Advance major version? ${version.major}" addproperty="updatemajor" validargs="y,n" defaultvalue="n" />
        <propertyfile file="./.ant/build.properties">
            <entry key="version.major" type="int" default="0" operation="+" pattern="00" />
        </propertyfile>

        <input message="Advance minor version? ${version.minor}" addproperty="updateminor" validargs="y,n" defaultvalue="y" />
        <propertyfile file="./.ant/build.properties">
            <entry key="version.minor" type="int" default="0" operation="+" pattern="00" />
        </propertyfile>
    </target>
</project>
```

And my build.properties

```
#Tue, 29 Mar 2011 11:46:30 -0400
version.buildnumber=35
version.major=2
version.minor=1
```

I am still very new to Ant so I am sorry that I can't post more advanced code.  So the first thing I need to do is add some kind of conditional around my property file edits.

Comment: Please provide more details about "kind of conditional".
Maybe AntForms (http://antforms.sourceforge.net/) is what you look for, form based interaction in ant scripts with some kind of logic, f.e. parameter required and optional, if and unless conditions for widget to exist .. etc. Recommended for form based interaction with ant !

Comment: Basically if the user answers yes (y) then update the property file, else don't do anything.  I really prefer to not use Antforms because then that takes away my ability to do my build from the command line which is important on this project.

Comment: Ant Flaka (http://code.google.com/p/flaka/) is a new Ant Plugin that provides an innovative Expression Language. Beside that Flaka provides conditional and repetitive control structures like when, unless, while, for, choose, switch .. So, for your conditional requirements you may use =
<project xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">
<fl:when test=" '${updatemajor}' eq 'y' ">
  your nested tasks ..
</fl:when>
for if|else you use the flaka choose|when|otherwise construct
For further details, see the comprehensive Flaka documentation = http://flaka.googlecode.com/files/flaka.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

what you want can be achieved by combining the condition and antcall task and by adding a couple of extra targets.

I think something like this should work:

```
<property file="./.ant/build.properties" />
<property name="sourceDir" location="/Users/dave/Workspace/ColdFusion/StudentMs" />
<property name="buildDir" location="${sourceDir}/builds" />

<target name="version" description="Adds a major and minor version to the build.">
    <input message="Advance major version? ${version.major}" addproperty="updatemajor" validargs="y,n" defaultvalue="n" />

     <condition property="executeMajor">
        <and>
           <isset property="updatemajor" />
           <equals arg1="${updatemajor}" arg2="y" />
        </and>
     </condition>

    <antcall target="update_major" />

    <input message="Advance minor version? ${version.minor}" addproperty="updateminor" validargs="y,n" defaultvalue="y" />

     <condition property="executeMinor">
        <and>
           <isset property="updateminor" />
           <equals arg1="${updateminor}" arg2="y" />
        </and>
     </condition>

   <antcall target="update_minor" />

</target>

<target name="update_major" if="executeMajor">
    <!-- Code to update major here -->
</target>

<target name="update_minor" if="executeMinor">
    <!-- Code to update minor here -->
</target>
```

Basically, what it does is set the executeMajor and executeMinor properties just in the case that the updatemajor/updateminor are set to "y". Then, ant will run the update targets just if the executeMajor/Minor variables are set, and it will skip them otherwise.

Comment: You can check the different used ant tasks in: [Condition](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/condition.html) [AntCall](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antcall.html)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would support both user input and an unattended build.

You can define ant properties on the command line. So, when you want to advance a version, you could do something like this:

```
      ant -Dbuild.version.advanceMinor=true
```

This approach would also allow you to avoid the extra steps on the majority of builds.

Comment: But that doesn't fix my question of needing to do a conditional.  I would still in my build file need to say `if advanceMinor == true do this; else don't do it` which is what I don't know how to do.

Comment: Oh! You can add an "if" attribute to targets, causing them to occur only if a property is defined. See http://ant.apache.org/manual/targets.html#targets . Also, there's a "condition" task that can set a property based on logical operators and conditions -- see http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/condition.html .